# Should my new steel stairs have a rubber gasket under for flexing?

Tags: concrete, stairs, steel

Building an all steel staircase in my workshop, with 6" C channel stringers. I'm wondering if I should put some rubber inner tube under the plates at the bottom of the stringers on the concrete to allow for deflection of the angle as people walk up and down. I built similar stairs at our old house, and they would start to squeak at that joint every few months until I tightened up the anchor nuts again. I think the bounce of the stairs was slowly working the anchors loose.

Comment: I have used foam like seal seal to separate the concrete from the steel, not for noise but to extend the life of the steel, rubber would probably work well also.

Comment: If the bolts are coming loose and need to be tightened every few months, consider using nylock nuts, lock washers or some thread locker on the bolts. For good quality overkill, use more than one method of locking.